# How can i get UserID from Telegram Bot

Tags: php, json, bots, telegram

I wanna get the userid and chatid from a user when he is in a chat with my bot because i need that Id for send querys to Sql and register that user but i dont have idea how can i get the userid :(

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($data,true);

$message = $update["message"];
$text = $message["text"];
$cid = $update["message"]["from"]["id"];
$from = $message["from"];
$username = $from["username"];
$nome = $from["first_name"];
$cognome = $form["last_name"];

$cbid = $update["callback_query"]["from"]["id"];
$cbdata = $update["callback_query"]["data"];
$chat_id = $message->chat->id;
$user_id = $message->from->id;
$user = $message->from->username;
```

And this code for send the UserID and ChatID to the chat

```
if($text == "Datos"){
$but = array(array(array("text" => "UserID", "callback_data" => "Info"),),);
inlineKeyboard($but, $cid, "Clicca uno di questi due pulsanti \nper andare su google o su facebook!");
}

if(callback($update)){
    if($cbdata == "Info"){
    send($cbid, "estos son los datos: $probando $user $userid $probando2");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the incoming data type? Json? Have you tried to var_dump() or print_r() the data array from the source youre getting the users info from in the first place to see if the attribute is available that youre after?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer i did : var_dump($data); and this is the info: string(0) ""

Comment: So you have no data coming from that variable. returning an empty string.

Comment: Yes i have no data from user_id i wanna know how the bot can get the user ID from a person when he/she send a message to the bot

Answer (score 1):

This is how I get userid or chat_id I'm not very sure but now I need that information for use in another part of the code but when I call again `$welcomemessage` the value of userid is empty. What should i do?

```
$userid = $message["from"]["id"];

$welcomemessage = "Este es tu id: $userid";

if ($text == '/hope') {
    $welcomemessage;

    // Send the generated message back to the Telegram user
    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".$welcomemessage);
}
```

Comment: Can you epxlain your code further? Why do you have a line that just contains `$welcomemessage` in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

This is the last code for get User ID i hope i will help somebody with this gl.

```
$userid = $message["from"]["id"];


if ($text == '/hope') {
    $userid;

    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatId.);
}
```